# How to properly define the hover template in Taipy GUI and how to remove the x-axis label?

Tags: python, user-interface, taipy

I would like to define the hover template in Taipy GUI like in plotly charts and I am also wondering about how to remove the x-axis label.

For example:

```
import pandas as pd

from taipy.gui import Gui

data = pd.DataFrame({

"questions": ["a", "b", "c"],

"answer": [2, 4, 5],

})

page = "<|{data}|chart|mode=lines+markers|x=questions|y=answer|>"

gui = Gui(page)

gui.run()
```